# Mips (assembly) - binary search problem - load not aligned for address of middle array element?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, offset, binary-search

```
        .text
        j main
        
binary_search:       
        slt $t0, $a2, $a1 # if last < first, $t0 = 1
        beq $t0, $zero, check_mid # if first > last, proceed to return -1   
    
        addi $v0, $zero, -1
        jr $ra # exit with returned argument
        
check_mid:
        # saving address to stack
        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
             
        sub $t1, $a2, $a1 # last - first
        srl $t1, $t1, 1 # (last - first) /2
     
        add $t2, $a1, $t1 # $t2 is referrencing the mid index of the array
        lw  $t3, 0($t2) # $t3 is the mid element of the array
        
        bne $t3, $a0, check_higher
    
        add $v0, $t2, $zero # $v0 is the index of the wanted element
        
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 4
        
        jr $ra # exit with returned argument
    
check_higher: 
        slt $t0, $t3, $a0 # if arr[mid] < x, $t0 is 1
        bne $t0, $zero, check_lower              
    
        addi $t1, $t1, -4 # mid = mid - 4
        jal binary_search # recursion call                
     
check_lower:
        addi $t1, $t1, 4 # mid = mid + 4
         jal binary_search # recursion call            
                      
main:
        addi $a0, $zero, 64
        addi $a1, $zero, 0
        addi $a2, $zero, 28
        jal binary_search
```

So this is my code so far. as far as I can see it I'm pretty much done with the code, unless I didn't take care well enough of saving/loading returning addresses from the stack, but that's not my main concern right now.

What I'm trying to figure out, is how do I reach the middle offset/element of the array? because executing this code will bring me the error: "line 39: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x0000000e" (line 39 is this line: `lw  $t3, 0($t2) # $t3 is the mid element of the array`)

Comment: Haven't looked thoroughly at your code, but I think you're working with byte offsets rather than element indices (which makes sense instead of redoing shifting for every index).  `srl $t1, $t1, 1` can thus produce an odd halfword address, instead of truncating down to an aligned word address.  You could AND with `-4`, or shift the bit all the way out the bottom then left-shift again back to where you want it.

Comment: @PeterCordes So if I understand correctly, by doing what I did [ (right-left)/2 ] I got to the middle of the index I wanted instead of the start of the index I wanted. So for example, if the array has 3 words in it, i'll get to the 6th bit instead of the 5th bit (which the new words start at)

Can you explain to me what's the difference between what you suggested? I don't think I understand the difference.

Comment: Memory is byte addressable, and words start at addresses that are multiples of 4 (bytes).  So not "5th bit", but yes if the array starts at address 0, then the middle word starts at address 4, the 5th byte.  But that's not a good example anyway because 8>>1 is 4, not shifting a 1 bit into the byte-within-word part of the address that needs to stay zero.  (Your code works with 0-based indexing, not 1-based counting.)  What I suggested is either `mid = ((hi-lo)>>3) << 1)` or `mid = ((hi-lo)>>1) & -4`, both of which are equivalent; clearing out the low 2 bits of the address.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have your MIPS simulator set up so the array starts at address `0`?  If not, you might have accidentally lost the pointer and been offsetting a zeroed register.  `0x0000000e` is an usually low address.  One of MARS's standard layouts puts `.data` starting at address 0, but it's not the default layout (because it makes it harder to notice NULL pointer bugs.)  Anyway, that would be a separate bug from the mid-point thing that's making the address an odd halfword.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with byte offsets instead of indexes for words. That's fine and good (instead of redoing left-shifting every time you use the address), but it means that a right shift won't truncate to a word offset, it can shift a bit into the byte-within-word part of the address, the low 2 bytes.  Unlike in C if you did `mid = (hi-lo)>>1;` which would simply shift a bit out the bottom of the value.

`srl $t1, $t1, 1` can thus produce an odd halfword address, instead of truncating down to an aligned word address.

You could `and` with `-4`, i.e. `0xfffffffc` to clear those address bits after shifting, but MIPS can't do that in one instruction because `andi` zero-extends its immediate.  If your array really is known to be smaller than 64KiB and at a very low address close to zero (so the `0x0000000e` you tried to deref wasn't also a separate bug of getting adding a small offset to a NULL pointer), you could `andi` with `0x0000fffc` to truncate an address.  Or do that on an offset before adding it to an actual address if you're working with offsets instead of actual pointers.

Of course you could just `li $t9, -4` once before your loop and use that, but you're using recursion instead of a more efficient loop.  So I guess you don't care about efficiency anyway and could just do an extra `li` right before you want to `and`.  (`addiu` can materialize a `-4` in one instruction, unlike `ori`.)

---

Or the other way would be to right shift the bits you want to discard all the way out of the register, and then to a left shift to bring you data back to where you want it.  `mid = ((hi-lo)>>3) << 1;`

---

**Also you have other bugs**, like falling off the bottom of your function after the `jal binary_search` in `check_lower:` returns.  You either need to reload `$ra` and return in those paths, or optimize the tail-call into a `j` or `b` after reloading `$ra`, not `jal` / reload `$ra` / `jr $ra`.

Same for the `jal` in `check_higher:`; you don't want to fall through into `check_lower`, that would end up checking both sides for O(N) total runtime, not O(log N).

But those are all things you should debug by single-stepping with a debugger, and separate from the interesting indexing problem of right-shift creating an odd-halfword address when doing binary search in asm with word addresses or byte offsets.

Comment: First of all thank you for all of the information and explanations. I'll be honest - I didn't understand it all, but I did try to improve my code and I think that overall I managed to do so. A friend suggested to use indexes and not to work with the array addresses so I tried that. I'm still getting an error when trying to load the arr[mid] value into a register and I can't figure out why.. (address out of range)

Edit: I tried to make a main method that adds to $a0 the X to find, $a1 the first address of the array and to $a2 the last address, but maybe this is what I'm doing wrong..